# Authentification ajax FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Symfony2 AJAX Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607212/symfony2-ajax-login)

I installed FOSUserBundle and It's ok.

I want to do authentication with ajax, my question: is there a tutorial that show step by step this solution?

Because I found some solution that does not have clear.

Comment: what defines this class directory AjaxAuthenticationListener ?