# Symfony 2 Ajax submit, Token CSRF invalid

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, symfony-forms

There is my problem, i need to submit forms in several steps. I have an **app form** and a **login form**

```
<form id="app_form" action="{{ path('app_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(formApp) }}>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">{{ form_label(formApp.name, 'Name'|trans) }}</div>
            <div class="span4">{{ form_widget(formApp.name, { required : true }) }}</div>
            <div class="span2" id="error_app_name">{{ form_errors(formApp.name) }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">{{ form_label(formApp.description, 'Description'|trans) }}</div>
            <div class="span4">{{ form_widget(formApp.description, { required : true }) }}</div>
            <div class="span2">{{ form_errors(formApp.description) }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">{{ form_label(formApp.iosUrl, 'iOS'|trans) }}</div>
            <div class="span4">{{ form_widget(formApp.iosUrl) }}</div>
            <div class="span2">{{ form_errors(formApp.iosUrl) }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">{{ form_label(formApp.androidBundle, 'Android Bundle'|trans) }}</div>
            <div class="span4">{{ form_widget(formApp.androidBundle) }}</div>
            <div class="span2">{{ form_errors(formApp.androidBundle) }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">{{ form_label(formApp.wpUrl, 'Windows Phone'|trans) }}</div>
            <div class="span4">{{ form_widget(formApp.wpUrl) }}</div>
            <div class="span2">{{ form_errors(formApp.wpUrl) }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">{{ form_label(formApp.bbUrl, 'Blackberry'|trans) }}</div>
            <div class="span4">{{ form_widget(formApp.bbUrl) }}</div>
            <div class="span2">{{ form_errors(formApp.bbUrl) }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">{{ form_label(formApp.fallbackUrl, 'Fallback Url'|trans) }}</div>
            <div class="span4">{{ form_widget(formApp.fallbackUrl) }}</div>
            <div class="span2">{{ form_errors(formApp.fallbackUrl) }}</div>
        </div>

        {{ form_rest(formApp) }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn">{{ 'Next step'|trans }}</button>

    </form>

<form id="form_login">
        <input type="hidden" id="login_csrf_token" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />

        <label for="login_username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
        <input type="text" id="login_username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="true" />

        <label for="login_password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>
        <input type="password" id="login_password" name="_password"  required="true" />

        <input type="checkbox" id="login_remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
        <label for="login_remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}</label>

        <button type="submit" class="btn">{{ 'Login'|trans }}</button>

        <button class="btn" id="register_show" type="button">{{ 'Want to register ?'|trans }}</button>

        <div id="error_login"></div>

    </form>
```

I want to submit the login form en ajax and then submit the app form, but when i do that i've got an error

> The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form

The Javascript code :

```
$('#form_login').submit(function(){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.post('./login_check', {   _csrf_token : $('#login_csrf_token').val() ,
                                        _username : $('#login_username').val() ,
                                        _password : $('#login_password').val(),
                                        _remember_me : $('#login_remember_me').val() },
                    function (data) {

                        console.log(data);
                        /**
                         * If the login was ok we submit the app form
                         */
                        if(data.success){
                            $('#app_form').submit();
                        }
                        /**
                         * Else we sow to the user the error
                         */
                        else{
                            $('#error_login').html(data.message);
                        }
                    }
            );
        });
```

The login form return success, but when i submit the app form **$('#app_form').submit();** the error appears in the next page.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSRF token uses, in part, cookies. When you generate two CSRFs on one page and submit one of the forms, you're invalidating the cookie.

Without some extensions on the framework itself, I can only really see one way around this -- and it's rather roundabout:

What you could do is set up a controller that generates your app form.

At the initial page load, your controller will load the login form as well as the app form. Upon submitting the login form via AJAX, you'll also request ONLY the controller for the app form (which will also give the user a new cookie). With javascript, you could then extract the NEW csrf token from the new form and inject it into the original app form. Then, when you submit the app form, it should have a new, valid csrf token.

To illustrate:

Get app form and login form -> submit login via AJAX -> get app form via AJAX in background -> steal new app form's csrf token and inject it into first app form -> submit app form.

Comment: Thx for your answer but actually i cant try your solution. The fact is that i dont have access to the treatment for the loginAction, i use a handler (Authentication handler) where i can notify that the login was successful or not and then send the response "success" to the javascript.
An another fact, i tried to do the same process with another action (registerAction, i submit the registerAction, which i can modify to return success or not, and then i submit the app form) and all the process work really well. 
So now im even more lost :/

Answer (score 3):

The solution i choose, was to re-generate the token in each LoginAjax action, and to send it in the response(which is formatted in JSON). Then I just have to update all the forms that has a token field (can be use by setting an specific class to each token.

First step by implementing a AuthenticationSuccessHandler
defined as this

```
acme.security.ajax_handler:
    class: Acme\UserBundle\Listener\AjaxAuthenticationListener
    arguments: ["@form.csrf_provider", "@router"]
```

The class AjaxAuthenticationListener

```
    <?php

namespace Travelyo\UserBundle\Listener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;

/**
 * Refere to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607212/symfony2-ajax-login
 * @author yoni
 *
 */
class AjaxAuthenticationListener implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface {

    protected $csrf_provider;
    protected $router;
    /**
     * In case we have Failure I need to provide a new csrf token
     * @param unknown_type $csrf_provider
     * @author Yoni Alhadeff
     */
    public function __construct($csrf_provider, $router)
    {
        $this->csrf_provider = $csrf_provider;
        $this->router = $router;
    }
    /**
     * This is called when an interactive authentication attempt succeeds. This
     * is called by authentication listeners inheriting from
     * AbstractAuthenticationListener.
     *
     * @see SymfonyComponentSecurityHttpFirewallAbstractAuthenticationListener
     * @param Request        $request
     * @param TokenInterface $token
     * @return Response the response to return
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            $result = array('success' => true, 'token'=>$this->csrf_provider->generateCsrfToken('unknown'));
            $response = new Response(json_encode($result));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $response;
        } else
        {
            // If the user tried to access a protected resource and was forces to login
            // redirect him back to that resource
            if ($targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.account.target_path'))
            {
                $url = $targetPath;
            } else
            {
                // Otherwise, redirect him to wherever you want
                $url = $this->router->generate('homepage_route_name', array());
            }
            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
    }
    /**
     * This is called when an interactive authentication attempt fails. This is
     * called by authentication listeners inheriting from
     * AbstractAuthenticationListener.
     *
     * @param Request                 $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $exception
     * @return Response the response to return
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
        {
            $result = array('success' => false, 'error'=>$exception->getMessage(),'token'=>$this->csrf_provider->generateCsrfToken('authenticate'));
            $response = new Response(json_encode($result));
            $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            return $response;
        } else
        {
            // Create a flash message with the authentication error message
            $request->getSession()->setFlash('error', $exception->getMessage());
            $url = $this->router->generate('fos_frontend_security_login');

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
    }
}
```

Both in the Failure & Success login when using AJAX, I add in the response the new token.

After wards in javascript, in the Succes: function () of the AJAX call, I just have to update the fields

something like that.

```
var route = $('#loginUrl').val();
var data= '_username=' +       $("#username").val()+"&_password="+$('#password').val()+"&_csrf_token="+$('#csrf_token').val();
$.ajax( {
    type : "POST",
    url : route,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache : false,
    success : function(response, value){
        //Response.success came from the JSON defined in the AjaxAuthenticationListener, he's not linked to the AJAX call
        if(response.success==true)
        {
        }

        $('#csrf_token').val(response.token); //Token has to be regenerate
        $(".tokenField").val(response.token);
    }
});
```

I think it's the easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('form').serialize()`:

```
$('#form_login').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:    $(this).attr('action'),
        method: $(this).attr('method'),
        data:   $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    });
});
```

In controller use following:

- `return new Response('ok')` for good response and
- `return new Response('bad :(', 500)` for bad response