# Symfony2 - routing after connecting

Tags: symfony

Currently, under Symfony2, when user is logging in, there is redirection to homepage. Is there a way to do no redirection and stay at the current page ?

Thanks.

Here is the security part

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: user
        form_login:
            login_path: /
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /
            check_path: /securite/connexion/check
        logout:
            path: app_security_logout
            target: app_homepage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect to the referer:

```
# app/config/security.yml security:

firewalls:
     main:
         form_login:
             # ...
             use_referer:        true
```

More info can be found here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html

Answer (score 0):

And you can do with ajax and fosuserbundle (for example) with this

[Symfony 2 FOS User Bundle Bootstrap modal AJAX Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445785/symfony-2-fos-user-bundle-bootstrap-modal-ajax-login)