# Set flashMessage from AuthenticationHandler in Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I'm having a problem with FOSUserBundle since any time I login with bad credentials I get the complete stacktrace as error message:

> Error! exception
>   'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException'
>   with message 'Bad credentials' in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php:90

And that is ugly for me so for users is very ugly. So I'm thinking in two solutions: change to AJAX login which I'm working on but it's not working or I'm doing something wrong (will explain below) and found a way to change that ugly message (I didn't get this one yet so any advice will be helpful).

Now regarding the first solution this is what I have done:

- Implements a `AuthenticationHandler`:

  ```
  <?php

  namespace UsuarioBundle\Handler;

  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
  use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

  class AuthenticationHandler
      implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface,
      AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
  {
      private $router;

      public function __construct(Router $router)
      {
          $this->router = $router;
      }

      public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
      {
          if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
              // do I need something here?
          } else {
              // If the user tried to access a protected resource and was forces to login
              // redirect him back to that resource
              if ($targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.target_path')) {
                  $url = $targetPath;
              } else {
                  // Otherwise, redirect him to wherever you want
                  $url = $this->router->generate('user_view', array('nickname' => $token->getUser()->getNickname()));
              }

              return new RedirectResponse($url);
          }
      }

      public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
      {
          if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
              // Handle XHR here
          } else {
              // Create a flash message with the authentication error message
              $request->getSession()->setFlash('error', $exception->getMessage());
              $url = $this->router->generate('user_login');

              return new RedirectResponse($url);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Define a service and register the handler:

  ```
  parameters:
      vendor_security.authentication_handler: UsuarioBundle\Handler\AuthenticationHandler

  services:
      authentication_handler:
          class:  %vendor_security.authentication_handler%
          arguments:  [@router]
          tags:
              - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
  ```
- Change the references in `security.yml`:

  firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                success_handler: authentication_handler
                failure_handler: authentication_handler

  ```
        logout:
             path: fos_user_security_logout
             target: /
             invalidate_session: false
        anonymous: ~
  ```

But I get this error when I try to login with invalid credentials:

> Attempted to call method "setFlash" on class
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session" in
>   /var/www/html/src/UsuarioBundle/Handler/AuthenticationHandler.php line
>   52.

Why? I check for `getSession()` method and it's part of `HttpFoundation` which I include in `use` statements, so what I'm doing wrong here?

Note: I take the code mostly from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607212/symfony2-ajax-login) topic so for that I'm still having some doubts around it.

Comment: I think you have to use session->getFlashBag()->add() instead of setFlash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$request->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'error');` was a notation for "old" symfony version.

Now you should use

```
$reqest->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('error', $exception->getMessage());
```

Moreover, are you sure that is a good practice to show `$exception` text message? I mean, I don't know in what page this flash will be shown BUT if a user, or even an admin - that of course doesn't knows pretty much anything about PHP and programming in general - can see tha page and so the message, you should try to log the message for your purpose BUT show something else to user.

Comment: Shouldn't be using `$this->get('session')` as the container hasn't been injected into the handler.

Comment: @Qoop: you're right: I was in "auto pilot" answer mode and didn't noticed that snippet of code wasn't a controller one

Comment: Phew.. I can relax again now.